# Why do ContinueWhenAll and ContinueWhenAny have unsupported TaskContinuationOptions?

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

When I go through documentation on MSDN and other books, I've seen that both functions have an overload that accepts a TaskContinuationOption.  But they can throw an exception according to this statement:

> It is invalid to exclude specific continuation kinds for continuations off of multiple tasks.

It seems that they only allow TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent, LongRunning, PreferFairness, ExecuteSynchronously and None, similar to the TaskCreationOption enum.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the invalid NotOn* and OnlyOn* TaskContinueOption values describe a continue option for a *single* task.  Which won't do, the ContinueWhenAll() and ContinueWhenAny() methods work with a *set* of tasks.  The internal method that checks the options and throws the ArgumentOutOfRange exception is named "CheckMultiTaskContinuationOptions", emphasis on *MultiTask*.